# Как хранить данные расписания движения транспорта в программе

Tags: java, алгоритм

Никак не могу определиться, как хранить данные расписания движения транспорта. Поискал, почитал по вопросу, что нашел... но разброс вариантов довольно большой, начиная с того, что все хранить в одном массиве, до создания кучи связанных таблиц (дерева).

Исходные данные такие: название остановки, вид транспорта, маршрут, рейс (для связи расписания с конкретным ТС), название следующей остановки, время прибытия, время отправления.

Подскажите, как лучше хранить вю эту инфу в программе для использования в поиске кратчайшего пути при котором учитывается расписание движения.

Как вариант думал создать класс в котором для каждого конкретного тр. средства и по каждой остановке хранилось инфа с временем прибытия и отправления:

```
public class Data {
private String Stop; // название остановки
private String Transport; // вид транспорта
private String Route; // маршрут
private String Flight; // рейс транспорта
private int[] timeOut; // время отправления по возрастанию
private int[] timeIn; // время прибытия по возрастанию
...
}
```

Но все ещё сомневаюсь.... насколько быстрым будет поиск данных по массиву (списку) этих объектов при формирования связей для графа...

Внесение изменений в уже соданное расписание не предполагается.

не хотелось бы в дальнейшем все переделывать, если понадобится что-то добавить в исходные данные, изменить или убрать....

Спасибо.

---

Пока кода никакого нету.... потому что не определился с форматом хранения расписания для возможно более быстрого поиска (основная проблема) по нему. Обдумывая как из расписания собрать данные в формате ориентированного графа (Узел1 - Узел2 - Вес) может оказаться, что потребуется, для формирования каждой связи просматривать весь массив целиком, что займет нереально много времени.

> Построение структуры данных при отсутствии опыта - путь проб и ошибок.

В этом убеждаючь постоянно :) это естественный процесс... но если есть на ориентировать, то бвло бы проще.

> А ещё, хранить и использовать - это разные понятия.
> согласен... но в планах "хранить, чтобы использовать" :)

В целом, меня интересуте даже не код, достаточно предложения, мысли, идеи... чтобы осознать возможные способы и, возможно, это наведет на какие-то свои собственные соображения на данный счет..

Comment: Нельзя вам помочь советом, пока вы не покажете код. Вы не покажете код, пока не напишите его. Вы не напишите его, пока не спроектируете данные. Построение структуры данных при отсутствии опыта - путь  проб и ошибок. Это нормально.

Comment: Если ты собираешься использовать графовые алгоритмы (поиск кратчайшего пути), то логично и данные иметь в виде графа. А ещё, хранить и использовать - это разные понятия.